# Ubuntu 22.04, locked screen idle after being given password

Tags: gnome, password, lock-screen, session

I have set my automatic screen lock after 5 minutes of not doing anything. Afterward, I can just log in back to my session. It used to work well until today. Now, whenever my screen is locked, I provide the correct password and nothing happens. I get the usual loading icon next to my password and it does nothing else. I click around, it asks for my password again.

If I change session (CTLR+ALT+F3), I can log in through the terminal interface without problem. But for GNOME, I need to restart my machine.

Anybody experienced something similar?